# Does the cleric's ability to spontaneously cast cure spells apply to the Breath of Life spell?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, class-feature, cleric, healing

Clerics have the ability to spontaneously cast a cure spell if they have a spell slot of the same level to trade out for it. Does this mechanic apply to *breath of life*?

Normally, I would think not; however, the way the [*breath of life*](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Breath%20of%20Life) spell reads is very similar to that of the other cure spells, and it even heals 1d8 more than the previous cure spell to keep the leveling trend going:

> This spell **cures** 5d8 points of damage + 1 point per caster level
> (maximum +25).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the ["spontaneous casting"](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/CLERIC/#Spontaneous_Casting) class feature for clerics (which is the one that allows this trade) clearly states.

> A cure spell is any spell with “cure” in its name

So no, a "breath of life" is not allowed by the rules as written.
Obviously, nothing is stopping your GM from allowing it anyway, but the rules are against you